# GPG signing commits in Centos 7 devcontainer from Windows 10 host

Tags: git, docker, gnupg, vscode-devcontainer

**Question:**
How do I configure VScode to use my gpg-agent credentials from a Windows 10 host? I followed [Microsoft's instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_using-ssh-keys) for configuring the ssh agent with vscode and I am able to utilize my ssh keys without mounting my <...>/.ssh directory in the container. I'm trying to acheive the same results with gpg. Their instructions for gpg, below the ssh section in the provided link, simply say that it can be done without explaining how to do it.

**Background/Setup information:**
I'm developing on a Windows 10 host machine. I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.51.1 and Docker Desktop version 3.1.0. On Windows I'm using git 2.29.1. My repository is designed to be cross platform and I could reasonably be working on the Windows side or the Linux side. The Linux development is inside a container based on a Centos 7 image. The image has git 2.30.0 installed. On Windows I am using gpg4win 3.1.7. The container does not have x installed and I can use pinentry-curses to sign commits in the container when I mount my .gnupg folder manually. My gitconfig specifies the path of the gpg.program so that I can sign the commits on the Windows side. When attempting to commit in the container, I get an error stating that it can't run : No such file or directory"

I have run `gpgconf --launch gpg-agent` on Windows. If it matters, here is my Windows gpg-agent.conf file. Located in C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\gnupg.

```
default-cache-ttl 34560000

max-cache-ttl 34560000
```